# class arrays sums, indexes, and calculation

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, indexing

Code:

```
class B {
public:
    B () : b(++bCounter) {}
    int b;
    static int bCounter;
};

int B::bCounter = 0;

class D : public B {
public:
    D () : d(0) {}
    int d;
};

const int N = 10;
B arrB[N];
D arrD[N];



int sum1 (B* arr) {
    int s = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) 
    {
        s+=arr[i].b;
    }
    return s;
}
int sum2 (D* arr) {
    int s = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        s+=arr[i].b+arr[i].d;
    }
    return s;
}
```

Question:

What do these return:

1) `sum1(arrB)`=?

2) `sum1(arrD)`=?

3) `sum2(arrD)`=?

When I compile & run these, I get 55, 65, and 155, and have no idea why. I gather that in arrB the variables are b=1,2,3,...,10, and in arrD b=11,12,...,20, so I would've answered sum1(arrB)=55 and sum1(arrD)=155 as in sum of 11+12+..+20, and sum2(arrD)=155, because everywhere d=0.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Needs `homework` tag ? Try stepping through the code in your debugger ?

Comment: It's not homework, I'm studying for an exam... And I tried debugging, but in the sum1(arrD) it's very strange, the `for` loop is skipping every 2nd value of indexes, but isn't skipping the values, I don't get it...

Comment: Make sure you're using a build with no optimisation enabled when you debug, e.g. `gcc -O0 ...`, otherwise single-steping can be problematic in optimised code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting object slicing. 
You are passing a `D*` array into a function that takes a `B*` array. `D` is initially bigger than `B`.

Each time you are doing `s+=arr[i].b;` you are moving the pointer *by the size of B*, while you need to move it *by the size of D*, so after each iteration the pointer is not moving one item forward.

```
[TheBPart|TheDPart][TheBPart|TheDPart][TheBPart|TheDPart]
^
|
iteration 0

[TheBPart|TheDPart][TheBPart|TheDPart][TheBPart|TheDPart]
         ^
         |
      iteration 1

[TheBPart|TheDPart][TheBPart|TheDPart][TheBPart|TheDPart]
                   ^
                   |
             iteration 2

[TheBPart|TheDPart][TheBPart|TheDPart][TheBPart|TheDPart]
                            ^
                            |
                          iteration 3
```

What happens in your particular case is that after each odd iteration it points to somewhere in the *middle* of the object of `D` class. This is only happening because `D` is exactly twice as big as `B`, otherwise the behavior would have been different.

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies in converting `arrD` to `arrB`. B has the size of 4 bytes while D has a size of 8 bytes.

While you convert D* to B* you actually jump in the memory 4 bytes per iteration rather than 8 bytes. arrD will hold the following values in memory if we take 4 bytes at a time

```
11   // arrD[0].b
0    // arrD[0].d
12   // arrD[1].b
0    // arrD[1].d
13   // arrD[2].b
0    // arrD[2].d
14   // arrD[3].b
0    // arrD[3].d
15   // arrD[4].b
0    // arrD[4].d
16   // arrD[5].b
0    // arrD[5].d
17   // arrD[6].b
0    // arrD[6].d
18   // arrD[7].b
0    // arrD[7].d
19   // arrD[8].b
0    // arrD[8].d
20   // arrD[9].b
0    // arrD[9].d
```

Now as you sum up taking 4 bytes at a time, you take the first 10 values of this. Hence your result is: 11+0+12+0+13+0+14+0+15+0 = 65

From similar reasoning you can know reason for your result for `sum2`.